# Unable to use ssh-add command. Error connecting to agent: No error

Tags: ssh, git-bash

Trying to use ssh-add, after creating an ssh key.

Getting the following error:

•   **Error connecting to agent: No error**

The ssh agent starts ok by the looks of it:

•   eval `ssh-agent`

which gives the response Agent pid 2059